# How can I have my database files in my specific folder and if Derby is only client/server?

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, derby

I have never used Derby but I've seen that it can be embeded in my java application. If I decide to make my application by derby is there a way to place my database files in my specified application directory so I expect it to be portable and when I copy the database files to another application which can use them they will be copied safely?(I think that it was impossible for mysql thus it has a global configuration)

By the way I'd like to know if Derby has a client/server access system or it can be used like SQLite. My database is so easy and I need no client/server structure. Do client/server structures reduce the performance when they are compared with SQLite structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derby is  an open source relational database implemented entirely in Java based on Java, Sql, JDBC standards.

> when I copy the database files to another application which can use
>   them they will be copied safely?

Yes it is portable and can be copied safely

> I'd like to know if Derby has a client/server access system or it can
>   be used like SQLite

Derby supports the more familiar client/server mode with the Derby Network Client JDBC driver and Derby Network Server. check this [link](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html)

for a full [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509cline/) on how to use Derby with eclipse I'd suggest you to read this tutorial written by IBM

Good Luck